# I have a data where 1100 is parent and 1101,1102,1103 are the child nodes. How to implement this in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

I have a data where 1100 is parent and 1101,1102,1103 are child nodes. How can I implement this thing in java what concept I use?
It's structure is like

```
1100
  1101
  1102
  1103
```

Comment: I have data like 1100 as my parent node and it contains further 3 child 1101,1102,1103. i need to hold all the data as 1100 as parent and rest as a child. which concept i need to use in java

Comment: does you child say `1101` have any childen?

Comment: Other than storage, what operations would you need to do on this structure?

Comment: i need it for the comparison purpose

Comment: how do you wish to compare?

Answer (score 3):

write a data structure for your nodes of tree:

```
public static class Node {
    private int value;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children;
}
```

and add some functionality like `addChild`, `removeChild`, `setParent`, `getValue` and ... as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Node` class that has references to its children which are specified in a `List<Node>`.

```
public class Node {
    private int data;
    private List<Node> children;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addChild(Node node) {
        this.children.add(node);
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() { //TODO: smarter way of encapsulation
        return this.children;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node mainNode = new Node(1100);
        mainNode.addChild(new Node(1101));
        mainNode.addChild(new Node(1102));
        mainNode.addChild(new Node(1103));
    }
}
```

If you need to know the parent for each child node, then you just need to add the Parent:

```
public class Node {
    private int data;
    private List<Node> children;
    private Node parent;

    public void setParent(Node node) { this.parent = node; }

    public Node getParent() { return parent; }
```

and in `addChild` method

```
    public void addChild(Node node) {
        this.children.add(node);
        node.setParent(this);
    }
```

In which case you **really** shouldn't have the `getChildren()` method exposed like that.